# Getting 500 internal server error with Auth component in Cakephp 2.1.1 stable version

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

My cakephp app 2.1.1 is currently running on Cent OS server and I keep getting 500 internal server error on random occasions whenever I try to log into the system using Auth component.

I thought it was something to do with Apache httpd.conf settings so I changed to AllowOverride All from None but it keeps on happening.

I'm not sure whether this is to do with .htaccess or something else with Cakephp.

Is this actually a bug for Cakephp 2.1.1?

**UPDATE 12/APR/2012**

**I'm getting below errors in log:**

```
2012-04-11 16:26:27 Warning: Warning (512): _cake_model_ cache was unable to write 'default_ticketing_jobs_localgovstategovfedjobs' to Apc cache in [/home/commstrat2_web/html/ticket/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 306]
Trace:
Cache::write() - CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 306
DataSource::_cacheDescription() - CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/DataSource.php, line 306
Mysql::describe() - CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php, line 334
Model::schema() - CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php, line 1281
DboSource::fields() - CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php, line 2180
DboSource::read() - CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php, line 1027
Model::find() - CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php, line 2635
JobsLocalgovstategovfedjobsController::index() - APP/Controller/JobsLocalgovstategovfedjobsController.php, line 38
ReflectionMethod::invokeArgs() - [internal], line ??
Controller::invokeAction() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php, line 488
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 103
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 85
[main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 96

2012-04-11 16:26:30 Warning: Warning (512): _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'file_map' to Apc cache in [/home/commstrat2_web/html/ticket/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 306]
Trace:
Cache::write() - CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 306
App::shutdown() - CORE/Cake/Core/App.php, line 884
[main] - [internal], line ??

2012-04-11 16:26:30 Warning: Warning (512): _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'method_cache' to Apc cache in [/home/commstrat2_web/html/ticket/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 306]
Trace:
Cache::write() - CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 306
DboSource::__destruct() - CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php, line 3148
[main] - [internal], line ??
```

Also when I enabled debug and try to log out below error aswell on browser:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function logout() on a non-object in /home/commstrat2_web/html/ticket/app/Controller/UsersController.php on line 117
```

When I turn off debug, it's just coming with blank screen this happens only when logging in and out.

Comment: Look in the PHP/CakePHP error logs. What is the error message?

Comment: Hi Juhana. I've just updated. What do you think?

Comment: Well obviously you have an error on line 117 of UsersController.php.

Comment: That's $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());

Comment: I also get error from $this->Auth->login(); could this be with Auth error?

Comment: It happens also to me when i enable APC cache in the php.ini

Answer (score 0):

This totally sounds like a file permission issue. Double check the app/tmp folder to make certain the permissions on the sub-directories are correct.